# roting component Angular not working in firefox

Tags: angular8

All my project works fine in google chrome browser but In firefox  when I login from loginComponent and navigate to the dashboardCompent , the component of login stay in the button of the page and I didn't get  the dynamic dashboard correct but after I refresh the window manually It works correct

this is my Code :

Parse.User
.logIn(this.loginForm.value.userName, this.loginForm.value.password).then(function (user) {

```
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']) ;
```

}).catch(function (error) {

```
self.errors = true ;
```

});

}

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you check if there are errors showing in your browser console? if its true, show the print please

Comment: thanks for your answer but I don't have any error in console

Comment: see this issue maybe help you: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3753

Comment: thanks but Unfortunately , didn't work

Comment: It's work now   
  Parse.User
  .logIn(this.loginForm.value.userName, this.loginForm.value.password).then(function (user) {

  }).catch(function (error) {
  
  });


 if (Parse.User.current().id) {
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']) ;
  }

  else {
    this.router.navigate(['/auth/login']) ;

  }

}


}

Comment: nice, I'm glad you corrected, you can add this solution in your answer, maybe more people have the same problem :)